# Adding attachment to PDF file with PHP or using bash

Tags: php, bash, pdf, attachment, mpdf

at the moment I am using mPDF to generate PDF files using PHP. After upgrading to PHP 7.2 and mPDF 7.1, file annotations stopped working (the annotation is still added but the file is not attached).
However I still need to attach an XML file to the PDF. What would be an easy way to do this, without loading another new PDF library. I wouldn't like to replace mPDF because there are lots of fine-tuned HTML templates for the PDF generation and I wouldn't like to redesign them. So for example a simple bash script would be great, but I couldn't find a script that could do this.

Any idea for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried opening mPDF issue ticket for that?

Comment: Yep, here is the URL for that: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/848

Comment: So why don't you provide the requested example files in the ticket?

Comment: "Does it make a difference which file you attach? If so, please provide an example file." It doesn't make any difference, so no example file is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the Issue at GitHub:

As you are upgrading from mPDF 6.x: since mPDF v7.0.0, embedded annotation files must be explicitly allowed by setting `allowAnnotationFiles` configuration key to true. Otherwise, the file attribute of annotation tag will be ignored.

Code below works with mPDF 7.1.5 and both PHP 7.1 and 7.2:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['allowAnnotationFiles' => true]);

$mpdf->Annotation("File annotation", 0, 0, 'Note', '', '', 0, false, '', 'assets/tiger.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks here as well! :)